# Documentation on wildcard syntax, such as for use in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()?

Tags: arcpy, wildcard

I was wondering if anyone knew where I could find some documentation on proper syntax for use of wildcards in arcpy, such as with the ListFeatureClasses function?

I have been unable to locate any thus far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an ArcPy Café blog posting on this subject titled [A handy wildcard tip](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/a-handy-wildcard-tip/) which highlights how to use a wildcard `*` in `ListFeatureClasses`:

```
# Set the workspace. List all feature classes that start with 'tax'.
arcpy.env.workspace = "d:/stjohns/localgovernment.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("tax*")
```

Additionally, the blog post also describes how to list all features that do not start with some search term:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "d:/stjohns/localgovernment.gdb"
fcs = [fc for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() if not fc.startswith('tax')]
```

ArcGIS has [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002t000000) on using wildcards in SQL expressions. For example:

> % means that anything is acceptable in its place: one character, a
>   hundred characters, or no character. Alternatively, if you want to
>   search with a wildcard that represents one character, use _.

From a pure python perspective, you can use wildcards to list certain files using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) ([link1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html?highlight=wildcard#file-wildcards), [link2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob))

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.py')
['primes.py', 'random.py', 'quote.py']
```

Comment: This was not the answer I was expecting, but I actually think it answers my question well!

I was expecting to get some documentation about different expressions that could be used directly as parameters to ListFeatureClasses(), but it did not occur to me to use regular string functions to filter them out rather than the ListFeatureClasses() function itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, what is the statement called that the ArcPy Cafe link uses?

Comment: The second example is a python data structure called a list comprehension. More details here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions